# Creating complex filters with CouchDB

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

I have a ionic app that's storing data in its local PouchDB.

My database stores documents like this example:

```
{
    Timestamp: "2016-11-17T09:35:06",
    Category: "CAT_1",
    Place: "House",
    ...
    Responsible: "Foo Bar",
    ...
},
{
    Timestamp: "2016-11-07T18:45:11",
    CategoryCode: "CAT_2",
    Place: "Apartment",
    ...
    Responsible: "Bar Foo",
    ...
}
```

My ionic app needs a filter screen where the user can pick any/all of these 4 fields and apply it for filtering.

So my app user can select only the `Timestamp` to search for ocurrencies only in a certain date. He can select filter all by a single `Category` and so on.

He can create any combination of these 4 elements, like:

```
[Timestamp,Category]
[Timestamp,Place]
[Category,Place]
[Timestamp,Responsible]
...
```

I always have to order inversely by `Timestamp`, but that is not the problem.

The problem is that I can't find any Map function that can give that type of flexibility...

I know that if the user had to fill all filters, I could easily use this Map function:

```
map: 
function (doc) {
    emit([Timestamp,Category,Place,Responsible], doc.Name);
}
```

With this, I know that I can query this possibilities:

```
[Timestamp,{}]
[Timestamp,Category,{}]
[Timestamp,Category,Place,{}]
[Timestamp,Category,Place,Responsible]
```

But I can't filter by only `[Place,Responsible]` because CouchDB/PouchDB don't let me put wildcards on the left like `[{},{},Place,Responsible]`, only on the right, like I showed before.

I know that I can create one Map for each possibility, but today we have **four** filters, tomorrow it can be **ten**!

Can some of you give me a hint of what I can do to cover it?

I know that my background on SQL should put me on the wrong direction, but I imagine that it can't be that hard to create a complex filter with NoSQL and specially CouchDB/PouchDB.

It's impossible that I'm the first one trying to do that.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do filters like this in Couchdb, as there is no way to do it in other NoSQL dbs. Even for SQL databases if your have an index on `[Timestamp,Category,Place,Responsible]`, you can't use it for searching `[{},{},Place,Responsible]`.

You may consider using full time search for couchdb, where you can specify any combinations of fields to search in any order:
https://github.com/cloudant-labs/clouseau
https://github.com/cloudant-labs/dreyfus

A caveat here is that search retrieves only first 200 records, after that you need to fire extra requests to paginate through results, while keeping a database unmodified.